Using Async and Await inside for loop in flutter
In my case, I have a list which contains some data. I need to give each data to API one by one.There are also some 'other functionalities' that I am doing before each API call to give some data to the API request.So I have given a for loop, and in each iteration I have set in such a way that the 'other functionalities' will work first and then the API call. I have made use of async and await. but 'for loop' will not wait for the API to finish. it runs all its iteration completely, and only 'other functionalities' inside the loop will work for each time. the problem is API may lag in that case. and there could be data mismatches also since I am giving certain data to the API from 'other functionalities'. I would like to know if there is any better idea in flutter to do this so that the next iteration only starts after the 'other functionalities' and the API call.
When I tried my way, all the 'other functionalities' completed in the first time and the API was still running one by one, also some API calls may get failed.
for (int i = 0; i < vehicleOutDetailsForApiCall.length; i++) {
    try {
      //api call
      final result = await vehicleMovementListOutUsecase
          .call(VehicleMovementListParams(
        vehicleMomentId: vehicleOutDetailsForApiCall[i].vehicleId,
        outDate: vehicleOutDetailsForApiCall[i].outDate,
        outTime: vehicleOutDetailsForApiCall[i].outTime,
        isVehicleOut: vehicleOutDetailsForApiCall[i].isVehicleOut,
      ));

      //handling success(r) and failure(l) of api
      result.fold((l) async {
        //error msg snackbar here
      }, (r) async {
        await deleteVehicleFromDb(
            vehiclePassNo:            vehicleOutDetailsForApiCall[i].vehiclePassNo.toString());
      });
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("the error in the unloading is $e");
    }
  }

In the above given example, if the vehicleOutDetailsForApiCall contains a length of 5. then all the five iterations will occur first, it will not wait for the api result(api success or failure). while the first api call is started, the for loop iteration may be already in 2 or 3 or is completed.hope the example helps.

Please include the code to clarify your problem.

updated in the question

Sounds like you should be using the await Future.wait().
Here's flutter's example:
void main() async {
  var value = await Future.wait([delayedNumber(), delayedString()]);
  print(value); // [2, result]
}

Future<int> delayedNumber() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  return 2;
}

Future<String> delayedString() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  return 'result';
}


But will this work inside a for loop..?
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
var value = await Future.wait([delayedNumber(), delayedString()]);
print(value);
}
Only after printing the value, it should go to next iteration of for loop.

Could you also provide the vehicleMovementListOutUsecase method? From what you're describing it seems it contains the actual async api call that you mentioned, which you're not actually await(ing). The fact that you use await on a method doesn't mean you're using await on its inner calls.

class VehicleMovementListOutUsecase
implements UseCaseWithParams<VehicleMovementListEntity, VehicleMovementListParams> {
final VehicleMovementListRepository vehicleMovementListRepository;
VehicleMovementListOutUsecase({required this.vehicleMovementListRepository});
@override
Future<Either<Failure, VehicleMovementListEntity>> call(vehicleMovementListOutParams) {
return vehicleMovementListRepository.outAPiCall(vehicleMovementListOutParams);
}
}

You can perform Asynchronous functions in a for loop like this:-
Future<void> processDataList(List<dataItem> dataList) async {
  for (var data in dataList) {
    // Perform other functionalities before the API call
    processedData = await performOtherFunctionalities(data);

    // Make the API call using `await` to wait for completion
    await makeApiCall(processedData);
  }
}

